# How to get owner of a guild in discord.js v13?

Tags: discord.js

In discord.js v12, `message.guild.owner` works but in discord.js v13, `interaction.guild.owner` does not work. How do I get owner of guild? I don't see `interaction.guild.owner` in docs. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Guild.fetchOwner`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner) method fetches the owner from the API and always returns the owner.

```js
//...
let owner = await interaction.guild.fetchOwner()
console.log(owner)
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs are always the best place to look for!
You may first get the `interaction.guild` for the `GuildObject`
and further use the [`.fetchOwner()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner) method on it, which returns us a promise with when fulfilled returns us the `GuildMember` object of the owner.